# Seaborn rugplot plot nothing

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization, seaborn

I'm trying to plot a rugplot using seaborn's rugplot method:

```
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
sns.rugplot(tips['total_bill'])
```

but the figure is empty:
[rugplot empty figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atM9R.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. The plot is shown correctly for me. Are you sure that is the code that you are using in its entirety?

Comment: Yes it is..
The most wierd thing is that if i add some kde plot it's suddenly works:

`sns.kdeplot(tips['total_bill'])`
`sns.rugplot(tips['total_bill'])`

Comment: According to [this](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html) there have been changes in rugplot. Maybe this should be filed as a bug?

Comment: This specific problem hasn't mentioned there, but thank you anyway..i just plot it with the kde :(

Answer (score 1):

There's been a change in seaborn 0.10.0 (https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html):

- Changed rugplot() to plot a matplotlib LineCollection instead of many Line2D objects, providing a big speedup for large arrays.

Seems like the new rugplot() is not working on its own anymore ... (?!)

Use instead:

```
sns.kdeplot(tips['total_bill'], ls="")

sns.rugplot(tips['total_bill'])
```

This first plots an invisible kdeplot, then inserts the rugplot.

Comment: Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @Yash Pandey: The second expression should be corrected as , sns.rugplot(tips['total_bill']), it is missing the closing paranthesis above.